# How to resolve a kernel panic on Ubuntu on my Lenovo Yoga 530?

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, lenovo

I had installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo Yoga 530.

After a bumpy start it did work but not very smoothly. I managed install by turning off security mode and start it with safe graphics option.

It would start crashing more often so I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 by using an USB.
The installer crashed and I could only access ubuntu live-CD, but then either keyboard or mouse cursor didn't work.

I tried replace the ISO-Image and did a checksum check.

After several tries I couldn't reach live-CD anymore and I would get a message that it couldn't load initramfs, then it would do a filesystem check and I end up with a kernel panic.
Thats where I am now.

I had quit for some time and returned now to see if I can fix this issue somehow.

Not sure if these information are any helpful. I have some text files from when I could still reach a terminal: casper.log, dmesg, kern.log, syslog, hwinfo.txt (where I stored some hardware information).
If you wish to see the content of any of them.

Maybe I could try to install a different distro would this be any helpful?

I also attached a picture of my screen
[Kernel panic message after "successfull" file system check with "no errors"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akjKR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that there is potentially file system corruption on the media, a dentry lookup failed, so this is clearly a corrupted filesystem.  Perhaps start over again by copying the ISO image to the installation media or use a different USB stick.

Comment: I tried using a different one, but it didn't work. Then I tried using disc image option in rufus, but same result unfortunately.